# AWS EventBridge Pattern for ECR Scan Issues

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecr, aws-event-bridge

I cannot quite figure it out, what is the Event Pattern required to trigger an EventBridge rule for when an ECR Scan comes back having found vulnerabilities at ANY level. Can anyone share an Event Pattern that would allow this?

Comment: I have since spoken to AWS Support about this and they confirmed that this is not possible. They have raised a Feature Request to get support added but no ETA. In the mean time the best you can do is have an Event Pattern for every vulnerability type. This could cause multiple events to be triggered but this is the only real work-around right now.

Answer (score 0):

You can find sample ECR Scanning events at https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECR/latest/userguide/ecr-eventbridge.html#ecr-eventbridge-bus

```
{
    "version": "0",
    "id": "85fc3613-e913-7fc4-a80c-a3753e4aa9ae",
    "detail-type": "ECR Image Scan",
    "source": "aws.ecr",
    "account": "123456789012",
    "time": "2019-10-29T02:36:48Z",
    "region": "us-east-1",
    "resources": [
        "arn:aws:ecr:us-east-1:123456789012:repository/my-repo"
    ],
    "detail": {
        "scan-status": "COMPLETE",
        "repository-name": "my-repo",
        "finding-severity-counts": {
           "CRITICAL": 10,
           "MEDIUM": 9
         },
        "image-digest": "sha256:7f5b2640fe6fb4f46592dfd3410c4a79dac4f89e4782432e0378abcd1234",
        "image-tags": []
    }
}
```

You can create a rule to match on values within `finding-severity-counts`. You may find this helpful https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eventbridge/latest/userguide/content-filtering-with-event-patterns.html#filtering-exists-matching

Comment: Yep I've read all of this. It doesn't solve the problem. You cannot currently have a rule that is essentially "if finding-severity-counts exists then match". This has been confirmed by AWS Support (see my own comment on my original question), though it has been raised as a Feature Request.

Comment: Ah gotcha, this is because exists-matching only works on leaf-nodes. Alternatively, have you considered just have multiple rules instead of a single rule. one for each severity ?

Comment: Yes, totally considered that but my team is sensitive to alert fatigue. And potentially having multiple alerts fire off for a single report won't go down well. I'll propose it to them regardless, but I'll keep this issue open I think so I can update hopefully when the feature request I mentioned above is completed.

Comment: All events the same events have a unique id (called event id). You can de-dupe against it in your code to ensure only a single event is sent downstream.

Comment: In what code? The EventBridge Rule pattern syntax doesn't allow any deduplication of this nature does it? I cannot see any mention of this kind of feature in the docs (and AWS Support themselves didn't mention it to me). Can you provide an example?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to achieve this by using the [$or matching content filter](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eventbridge/latest/userguide/eb-event-patterns-content-based-filtering.html#eb-filtering-complex-example-or).

The following event pattern matches if any of LOW, MEDIUM, HIGH or CRITICAL vulnerabilities are found in the image scan results:

```
{
  "source": ["aws.ecr"],
  "detail-type": ["ECR Image Scan"],
  "detail": {
    "finding-severity-counts": {
      "$or": [{
        "CRITICAL": [{
          "exists": true
        }]
      }, {
        "HIGH": [{
          "exists": true
        }]
      }, {
        "MEDIUM": [{
          "exists": true
        }]
      }, {
        "LOW": [{
          "exists": true
        }]
      }]
    }
  }
}
```

This event pattern will trigger a single match even if multiple types of vulnerabilities are found.

Answer (score 0):

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Description: Forward EventBridge security events to AWS SNS
  EcrVulnerabilitiesEventRule:
    Type: AWS::Events::Rule
    Properties:
      Name: detect-ecr-vulnerabilities
      Description: A CloudWatch Event Rule that triggers on Amazon ECR vulnerabilities.
      State: ENABLED
      EventPattern:
        source:
          -  aws.ecr
        detail-type:
          - ECR Image Scan
        detail:
          finding-severity-counts:
            CRITICAL:
              - exists: false
              - numeric: [ ">", 0 ]
            HIGH:
              - exists: false
              - numeric: [ ">", 0 ]
            MEDIUM:
              - exists: false
              - numeric: [ ">", 0 ]
            # UNDEFINED:
            #   - exists: false
            #   - numeric: [ ">", 0 ]
      Targets:
        - Arn:
            Ref: SecurityIssuesSnsTopic
          Id: SecurityTopic
```

Comment: I cannot seem to find this answer anywhere and the docs are quite confusing... for ECR actions in AWS do you need to explicitly configure any CloudFormation components or any other mechanisms for events to be captured in AWS EventBridge?

I have scans enabled continuous which I can verify in the UI as well as auditing such as pulls etc. For debugging, my Event Pattern right now is super simple:

```
{
  "source": ["aws.ecr"]
}
```

However, I go to the "Monitoring" tab of the EventBridge in question and see zero results.. Any ideas? Please help, hoping this should be an easy one!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).